# If name in Column A2:A837 is also in Column P2:P33, then return value in Column M of corresponding A row

Tags: excel

I have one Excel Sheet. A list of 836 names are in Column A, a list of 332 names are in Column P.  I want a formula so that if the name in Column A2:A837 is listed in Column P2:P33, then it will return the value listed in Column M of corresponding A row where the student name matched the name in column P.

```
Student Name (Column A)
Total Truancies (Column M)
Free/Reduced Students (Column P)
Total Truancies of Free/Reduced students (Column N)
```

I want the total truancies value (Column M) to show up in Column N, ONLY if the student listed in Column A is on the Free/Reduced list of Column P)

Comment: Try a combination of `if`, `iserror` and `vlookup`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may have better luck if you post what you have tried when asking a question.  See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see your spreadsheet I'm typing this in the dark:

```
// Cell N2
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,P:P,1,FALSE)),0,M2)
                                     ^--- change this to whatever you want when
                                          the student is not found on column P
```

Answer (score 0):

In cell "M" enter the following formula:
=VLOOKUP(A2;$P$332;1;FALSE)

You may have to replace the arguments with "," instead of ";"

Then copy it to the last row of data in the column "A".

This I write with syntax Excel 97-2003

Regards!